# Using XQuery to return multiple attributes using different conditions

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-sql

I am new to XQuery and I am trying to figure out something really simple but I seem to be failing miserably.
I have an XML file of Employees in a Company which looks like this:

```
<dataroot>


<employee>


    <fname>John</fname>


    <minit>B</minit>


    <lname>Smith</lname>


    <ssn>123456789</ssn>


    <bdate>1965-01-09</bdate>


    <address>731 Fondren, Houston, TX</address>


    <sex>M</sex>


    <salary>30000</salary>


    <superssn>333445555</superssn>


    <dno>5</dno>


</employee>


<employee>


    <fname>Franklin</fname>


    <minit>T</minit>


    <lname>Wong</lname>


    <ssn>333445555</ssn>


    <bdate>1955-12-08</bdate>


    <address>638 Voss, Houston, TX</address>


    <sex>M</sex>


    <salary>40000</salary>


    <superssn>888665555</superssn>


    <dno>5</dno>


</employee>
...etc
```

And that goes on for all the Employees. I also have a Dependents XML file which looks like this:

```
<dependent>


    <essn>123456789</essn>


    <dependent_name>Alice</dependent_name>


    <sex>F</sex>


    <bdate>1988-12-30</bdate>


    <relationship>daughter</relationship>


</dependent>


<dependent>


    <essn>123456789</essn>


    <dependent_name>Elizabeth</dependent_name>


    <sex>F</sex>


    <bdate>1967-05-05</bdate>


    <relationship>spouse</relationship>


</dependent>
...and so on
```

My problem is that I'm trying to run an XQuery that returns the name of the dependent, first name and last name of the employee related to that dependent AND the first name and last name of that employee's manager.
I'm having trouble when it comes to accessing the managers information seeing as the manager's ssn has to be compared to the employee's ssn to get the name of the manager (both regular employees and managers are part of the employee file).

This is what I have so far:

```
<results>
{
    for $e in doc("../company/employee.xml")//employee,
        $m in doc("../company/employee.xml")//employee
        $d in doc("../company/dependent.xml")//dependent
    return
        <ans
            dname="{ $d/dependent_name }"
            emp fname="{ $e/fname }"
            emp lname="{ $e/lname }"
            mgr fname="{ } (: *this is where I get lost* :)
        />
}
</results>
```

So I guess my specific question is: 
Seeing as I can access each Employee from the Employee.xml and each Dependent from the Dependent.xml files WITHOUT using a conditional (WHERE $e/superssn = $m/essn) how can I return all those values since only one of the returned results requires a conditional statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly get the your actual question and why you would want to not a a condition, but it seems to me because you are missing or mixing up some concepts in your XQuery.

First of all, if you write

```
for $e in doc("../company/employee.xml")//employee,
    $m in doc("../company/employee.xml")//employee
    $d in doc("../company/dependent.xml")//dependent
```

this are three interleaved for loops, which seems totally unnecessary. If I understood correctly you want to get an employee and all of his/her dependents and the employees manager. You should use `let` for this

```
for $e in doc("../company/employee.xml")/dataroot/employee
for $d in doc("../company/dependent.xml")//dependent[essn = $e/ssn]
let $m in doc("../company/employee.xml")/dataroot/employee[ssn = $e/superssn]
return
    <ans
        dname="{ $d/dependent_name }"
        emp fname="{ $e/fname }"
        emp lname="{ $e/lname }"
        mgr fname="{ $m/fname }
    />
```

I also replaced `//` with a concrete step. You should try to avoid `//` wherever possible as it has to search the whole tree and this can be quite large.

And please use more meaningful variable names than `$m`. `$manager` is much more easy to read and it doesn't cost you a thing.

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you so much! I was definitely misunderstanding the proper use of 'let' and thus I was even more confused. I will take your advice and use the concrete step as well. Very helpful, thanks again.

Comment: @mugiwaragirl voting up (and if it solved your problem accepting the answer) and answer is  saying "thank you" on SO. And seeing that you are a quite inexperienced user (based on your rep): Welcome to SO :) And of course to the wonderful weird world of XQuery as well ;)

Comment: Yes I am brand new, how could you tell? ;) I appreciate the warm welcome!